# Set value to a datepicker without clicking 'Done' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datepicker, webix

I'm using the Webix time picker and have no idea how to force it to set the value without clicking the "Done" button (I don't want to display it at all). Is there a way to do this through the DOM or through the plain JS?

For example, a time picker (a datepicker with `type:"time"`)

```
var time = webix.ui({   
    view:"datepicker", 
    align: "right",
    label: 'Select Date',
    labelWidth:100, width:350,
    type:"time", stringResult:true
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/232a2e2c

Comment: I modify your code a little; now you can select the date value when you hit the enter key: http://webix.com/snippet/8bbb15e3

Comment: @Hackerman thanks, it's a great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a similar solution for my project using DOM. Works good enough for me, but actually, it's a temporary hack (unless I can find something better). Check it out:

```
time.getPopup().attachEvent("onhide", function(){
  var timeArr = document.getElementsByClassName("webix_cal_block webix_selected");
  if (timeArr.length == 2){
    var hour = timeArr[0].getAttribute("data-value");
    var min = timeArr[1].getAttribute("data-value");
    time.setValue(hour+" "+min);
  }  
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/ff554921

Comment: Thanks! With a solution provided by @Hackerman it will work as I need

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a little. Now you can select a date hitting the `Enter` key:

```
var time = webix.ui({   
   view:"datepicker", 
   align: "right",
   label: 'Select Date',
   labelWidth:100, width:350,
   type:"time", stringResult:true
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==13) {
     var done = document.getElementsByClassName('webix_cal_done');
     if(done.length > 0){
        done[0].click();
     }
  }
}
```

#### Working fiddle: http://webix.com/snippet/91f4cecc

Answer (score 1):

all done in one script:

```
var time = webix.ui({   
    view:"datepicker", 
    align: "right",
    label: 'Select Date',
    labelWidth:100, width:350,
    type:"time", stringResult:true
}).attachEvent("onBlur", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('webix_cal_done')[0].click();
});
```

thanks @Hackerman http://webix.com/snippet/1613c3d2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I would look at using [datepicker()](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) directly instead of using ui. its part of the jquery UI set. I have linked directly to the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) site.

```
var time = webix.datepicker();
```

And on the jquery page there is a list of time picker plugins that may also help fill the void
[Timepicker plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timepicker/)

Comment: Well, I still prefer to use Webix for my project, so I'm interested in the solution with this widget. But thanks anyways.